# Can climate change make humans require oxygen masks to breathe?

Tags: earth, far-future, climate-change, oxygen

I'm making a story where criminals are exiled to an uninhabitable, dying, resourceless Earth.

The prisoners must wear oxygen masks/protective suits in order to breathe on Earth's now heavilly polluted surface.

My question is, when will Earth get to this state?

Thanks for reading this :)

Comment: Welcome. When does your story need it to? We solve worldbuilding problems, not make story decisions (nor predict real-world events). Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. Enjoy the site.

Comment: Ok. Guess I won't ask then. Boom! Problem solved. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR version: This effect would be localized.

There is a strong tendency to convolute climate change and pollution. Climate change is causing an overall increase in temperature, a generalized shift in were moisture accumulates, and the acidification of the oceans. None of this results in less oxygen on the surface.

There are some parts of the world where wearing a filtration mask is necessary to keep your lungs from getting damaged due to the industrial pollutants. Most of the world recognizes that it creates an environment where people can't safely live much less work, so anywhere with a responsible government will force the industries to clean up their emissions, or to convert it into a disposable form, the way we do with fly ash. There are a few counter examples, like [Beijing](https://www.unep.org/interactive/beat-air-pollution/) but even the worst of the industrialists recognize that you can't have industry without workers.

For the entire planet to get that way, you would need highly automated (workerless) industry and some kind of global catastrophe that wiped out almost all of the plant life.

Comment: “some kind of global catastrophe that wiped out almost all of the plant life.” So like… climate change?

Comment: This answer completely neglects the fact that mass global deforestation will significantly reduce the amount of breathable oxygen in the atmosphere. Deforestation gets worse as the climate heats up and dries out, and as water tables become more acidic.

Comment: So, funny thing, land plants in general will be able to adapt to climate change just fine. In a worst case scenario, we'll lose some of the longer lived plants, like the sequoia, but smaller plants, like thistle, will happily fill in the gap. Sea creatures won't survive the acidification, and a lot of land creatures won't be able to find the things that they, specifically, eat in their territory, but the plants will keep growing. Deforestation and urban sprawl will primarily cause biodiversity loss, but the idea that it could deplete oxygen is nonsensical. 2067 has crap science.

Comment: @Topcode, no.  Climate change alone won't do it -- there are plenty of heat-tolerant or cold-tolerant plants willing to move in response to any temperature shifts.  In order to drop the oxygen level, you need a *drastic* climate change on the order of a snowball Earth or a runaway greenhouse.

Comment: @Mark “or a runaway greenhouse” so kinda like… climate change.

Comment: @Topcode, no.  A runaway greenhouse is when increasing temperatures themselves become the cause of further temperature increases in a positive-feedback cycle.  Here on Earth, we're nowhere near that point (and may never reach it -- there may be enough negative-feedback factors such as increasing cloud cover to prevent a runaway.)

Comment: @Mark “and may never reach it -- there may be enough negative-feedback factors such as increasing cloud cover to prevent a runaway.” that never stopped world building before.

Comment: @Topcode OP asked, "when will Earth get to this state?" If the Earth will never get to that state, I would expect the answer to say just that.

Comment: @Invizio realistically the user is not asking “in a completely static society from the current point in history when will the earth reach a point at which it is no longer consisting of a majority of breathable air” but “can the earth reasonably become unbreathable but otherwise inhabitable”

Comment: Robert gave a great answer without convoluting it with politics. I've been listening to environmental activists claim the Earth was on the brink of environmental disaster ("irreversible damage in the next 5 years!") since the 1970s and there's been too much research about climate change being affected by a lot of things: both man-made and natural - to believe it's the crisis everyone thinks it is. The planet will be fine. The problem is keeping the humans alive - which is what the OP is asking about - and Robert's right. It's not climate change that will cause our demise.

Comment: @Topcode Let us [continue in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138832/robert-rappleans-answer)

Comment: So, to clarify, the planet has been through cycles of extra warm and snowballing and, even in the Great Dying (when CO2 levels hit around 4k ppm), oxygen levels weren't depleted, or even notably reduced. I'm not making any claims about whether the climate crisis is going to kill us, I'm just claiming that low O2 levels aren't the path it will take.

Comment: That said, deforestation could possibly result in a reduction of biodiversity, which makes the entire ecosystem susceptible to strains that can wipe out large populations of plants. I just haven't seen evidence that it would (or even could) kill ALL plants. The things that COULD cause that, like a bioengineering disaster or grey goo, would be adequately problematic that _oxygen_levels_ would not be the concern. You'd need full containment suits and severely toxic scrubbing on exit.

Answer (score 3):

**Oceans die**

Fine SF concept lifted from Soylent Green.  Oceans are dying and with them go 80% of the oxygen.  The oxygen that is produced from forests high in Siberia is consumed by fires that burn in the dessicated, deserted lands farther south.  These fires burn until local oxygen is gone, then start up again if some shows up.

Your people need masks for supplemental oxygen.  Ambient oxygen in most places is only about 5%.

Comment: Two problems with this: 1) oceans don't just die.  Killing off the phytoplankton in the ocean is hard, and there's so much of it that something will quickly evolve to deal with any changing conditions.  2) Wildfires require oxygen.  I know this sounds obvious, but it means that as the oxygen levels drop, it gets harder for fires to start and grow.  Wildfires require more oxygen than humans do, so you'll eventually reach a point where humans can still breathe, but fires can't start.

Comment: @Mark - so you are saying soylent green really is made of plankton?